# Is there any way to lock the dock?

Tags: plank, icons

You can drag the icons on the dock and put them in and out, but is there any way of locking them so you can't do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can open the dock's preferences by right-clicking on a free space of the dock. Probably you will need several tries not to open context menu from an icon - but believe me, there are preferences:

[image]

For me the easiest way to open the preference window was the rightmost bottom of the dock (for bottom-placed dock). In the 'behaviour' tab you can lock the icons.

Comment: I can't stop wondering why this is not in settings > desktop > dock, but ok. Thanks!

Comment: you can you the command `plank --preferences`

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the other answer:

The command for the Plank settings UI is:

`plank --preferences`.

To find that with your applications launcher in the future (using `gedit` text editor):

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/plank_preferences.desktop
```

then paste this & save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Plank Settings
Exec=plank --preferences
Icon=plank
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;
X-GNOME-Keywords=Center;Control;Panel;Preferences;System;
X-AppInstall-Keywords=Center;Control;Panel;Preferences;System;
X-GNOME-Gettext-Domain=switchboard
Actions=AboutDialog;
```

[image]

To make changes like the one you mention one can also edit the file  `~/.config/plank/dock1/settings` which contains detailed description of the possible options. To lock the icons go to line

```
#Whether to prevent drag'n'drop actions and lock items on the dock.
LockItems=false
```

and change that to `true`.